# How to make Android Room ignore a constructor of a library class?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am trying to embed a POJO into an Android Room entity. However, when doing so, I receive the following errors (class name changed):

- *There are multiple good constructors and Room will pick the no-arg constructor. You can use the @Ignore annotation to eliminate unwanted constructors. - LibraryPojo*
- *Cannot find setter for field. - timeOfCreation in LibraryPojo*

This is the POJO I am trying to embed:

```java
public class LibraryPojo {
    private final long timeOfCreation;

    public LibraryPojo(long timeOfCreation) {
        this.timeOfCreation = timeOfCreation;
    }

    public LibraryPojo() {
        this(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public long getTimeOfCreation() {
        return timeOfCreation;
    }
}
```

Inside my entity I am doing this:

```
@Embedded
final LibraryPojo pojo;
```

If I remove the no-args constructor, it works fine.
**The catch is, I can't add the `@Ignore` annotation to this constructor**, because this class is part of a plain Java library and thus cannot access android classes.

I don't want to change the library class due to the separation of concerns (it's not the library's job to get the database to work!).
I also don't want to subclass `LibraryPojo` to hide to superclass constructor, because that would force me to embed the subclass. This in turn prevents me from assigning instances of `LibraryPojo` to that field, forcing me to instead create an instance of the subclass every time.

Isn't there any better way to hide constructors from Room without changing the class that declares them?

Comment: Room will not allow to ignore no-arg constructor, so you have to add `@Ignore` before one arg constructor  `@Ignore public LibraryPojo(long timeOfCreation) {
        this.timeOfCreation = timeOfCreation;
    }`

Comment: As stated in my question, I cannot add `@Ignore` to the `LibraryPojo` class, as it's part of a plain Java library and thus has no access to android framework classes.

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove the no-args constructor, it works fine. The catch is, I can't add the @Ignore annotation to this constructor, because this class is part of a plain Java library and thus cannot access android classes.

> As stated in my question, I cannot add @Ignore to the LibraryPojo class, as it's part of a plain Java library and thus has no access to android framework classes.

**You can use @Ignore in the LibraryPojo class.**

Here's a working example that demonstrates using `@Ignore` in a POJO and I think what you are trying to accomplish :-

**LibraryPojo** :-

```
public class LibraryPojo {

    long timeOfCreation;

    LibraryPojo() {
        this.timeOfCreation = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Ignore
    LibraryPojo(long timeOfCreation) {
        this.timeOfCreation = timeOfCreation;
    }

    public long getTimeOfCreation() {
        return timeOfCreation;
    }

    public void setTimeOfCreation(long timeOfCreation) {
        this.timeOfCreation = timeOfCreation;
    }
}
```

The Entity with LibraryPojo embedded **LibraryExtended** (itself with `@Ignore`d constructor) :-

```
@Entity
class LibraryExtended {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id;
    @Embedded
    LibraryPojo pojo;
    String name;

    LibraryExtended(){}

    @Ignore
    LibraryExtended(LibraryPojo pojo, String name) {
        this.pojo = pojo;
        this.name = name;
        this.id  = -1L;
    }
}
```

A basic Dao **LibraryDao** :-

```
@Dao
abstract class LibraryDao {

    @Insert
    abstract long insert(LibraryExtended le);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM libraryextended")
    abstract List<LibraryExtended> getAll();

}
```

A basic @Database class **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = {LibraryExtended.class}, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract LibraryDao getLibraryDao();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance = null;

    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"library.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Finally accessing the DB from an activity, storing a row and then extracting the row:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    LibraryDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getLibraryDao();
        LibraryExtended le = new LibraryExtended(new LibraryPojo(0L),"mylibrarryextended");
        dao.insert(le);
        for(LibraryExtended l: dao.getAll()) {
            Log.d("LIBINFO","Name is " + l.name + " id is " + String.valueOf(l.id));
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

The log includes :-

```
D/LIBINFO: Name is mylibrarryextended id is -1
```

Comment: The problem is, I'd have to import `androidx.room.Ignore` in the class `LibraryPojo` for that to work. That means, the library would require `androidx.room:room-common` in its classpath.
But wouldn't that break the library outside of the android framework? Because yes, `LibraryPojo` must also work when used in a plain Java environment!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to ignore no-args constructor in **Kotlin** is:
@Ignore
constructor() : this(0)

For example:

```
@Entity(tableName = "daily_sleep_quality_table")
data class SleepNight(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
                      var nightId: Long = 0L,

                      @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time_milli")
                      val startTimeMilli: Long =  System.currentTimeMillis(),

                      @ColumnInfo(name = "end_time_milli")
                      var endTimeMilli: Long = startTimeMilli,

                      @ColumnInfo(name = "quality_rating")
                      var sleepQuality: Int = -1
){
    @Ignore
    constructor() : this(0)
}
```

That should do the trick :)

Comment: Well beside the fact that I need a solution in Java, this one also seems to not solve the problem that **I cannot add @Ignore to the POJO class** as it is not part of an android library.

Comment: The final solution was that I had to downgrade Kotlin plugin to classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin: 1.4.32 The all works without @Ignore